# Text detection using Vision Framework with ObjectiveC on iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, computer-vision

I've a question, my question it is not about how to get the NSString from a box jeje (there are many questions of this) but my doubt is; what is wrong with this code? I want to detect characters from an image taken by a camera using obviously Vision Framework, more detailed VNTextObservation, so:

This is the code for take the image:

```
uiimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.imageToAnalyze.image = uiimage;
self.originalUIImageView.image = uiimage;
CIImage *ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:uiimage.CGImage];

self.imageToAnalyis = [ciImage imageByApplyingOrientation:[uiimage imageOrientation]];

[self startToAnalyze:ciImage];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The startToAnalyze method is this:

```
-(void) startToAnalyze:(CIImage *)image {

NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

// Create a requestHandler
VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCIImage:image orientation:(CGImagePropertyOrientation)[uiimage imageOrientation] options:d];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest *request = [[VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest alloc] initWithCompletionHandler:^(VNRequest * _Nonnull request, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        else {
            for (VNTextObservation *textObservation in request.results) {
//                                    NSLog(@"TO - %@", textObservation);
//                                    NSLog(@"TC - %@", textObservation.characterBoxes);
                    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(textObservation.boundingBox));


               for (VNTextObservation *box in request.results) {

                   NSArray *chars = box.characterBoxes;
                   if (chars.count != 0) {
                       NSLog(@"tiene boxes");
                   } else {
                       return;
                   }
                   for (VNTextObservation *char1 in chars) {
                       UIView *viewSample = [self createBoxViewWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
                       viewSample.frame = [self transformRect:char1.boundingBox to:self.imageToAnalyze];
                       self.imageToAnalyze.image = self.originalUIImageView.image;
                       [self.imageToAnalyze addSubview:viewSample];
                   }
               }

            }
        }
    }];
    request.reportCharacterBoxes = TRUE;
    NSError *error;
    [handler performRequests:@[request] error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }

});


}
```

The methods that I use to draw rectangles are here:

```
-(UIView *) createBoxViewWithColor:(UIColor *)color {

UIView *sampleView = [[UIView alloc] init];

sampleView.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor;
sampleView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
sampleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return sampleView;
}

-(CGRect)transformRect:(CGRect)FromRect to:(UIView *)viewRect {


// -(FromRect.size.height * viewRect.frame.size.height),

CGRect toRect = (CGRect) {
    toRect.size.width = FromRect.size.width * viewRect.frame.size.width,
    toRect.size.height = FromRect.size.height * viewRect.frame.size.height,
    toRect.origin.y = ((viewRect.frame.size.height) - (viewRect.frame.size.height * FromRect.origin.y)),
//        toRect.origin.y = toRect.origin.y - toRect.size.height,
        toRect.origin.x = FromRect.origin.x * viewRect.frame.size.width


};

return toRect;
}
```

With this code the rectangles shows like this and obviously is bad.
Could you please help me!

[image]